# Как экспортировать из файла App.js не только компонент App но и также массив что находится за пределами комопонента App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

В файл index.js я передал компонент App:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App attributeApp={carsArray} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Но у меня кроме компонента App в файле App.js есть еще массив **carsArray**:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import createBrowserHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";
import './App.css';
import Header from "./smallComponents/Header.js";
import Footer from "./smallComponents/Footer.js";
import Home from "./pageComponents/Home.js";
import About from "./pageComponents/About.js";
import Contacts from "./pageComponents/Contacts.js";
import CarsList from "./pageComponents/CarsList.js";

let carsArray = [
{
    id:1,
    name: 'BMW',
    phone: '555 555 5555'
}, 
{
    id:2,
    name: 'Mercedes',
    phone: '555 111 5555'
},
{
    id:3,
    name: 'Audi',
    phone: '555 777 5555'
},
{
    id:4,
    name: 'Ford',
    phone: '555 888 5555'
}
]

const history = createBrowserHistory();

class App extends React.Component {
  render(){ 
    return (
      <BrowserRouter history={history}> 
         <div className="wrapper">

        <Header/>

       <CarsList attributeCarsList={this.props.attributeApp}/>

            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} /> 
              <Route path="/about" component={About} />
              <Route path="/contacts" component={Contacts} />
            </Switch>

        <Footer/>          

       </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
   )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Если массив не передать в index.js то будет ошибка.

что написать после:
export default.....
что б передать и компонент и массив в index.js?
и как написать импорт масива в index.js?

Comment: Вы хотите импортировать данные из App, чтобы потом через свойства компонента передать их обратно в App?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю будет как то так. В файле app.js `export {carsArray}` 
Тогда в файле index.js будет `import { carsArray} from './App.js'`